# Extjs 4 grid mouseover show full cell value

Tags: javascript, grid, extjs4, javascript-framework

I've got a grid with a long string in one of the columns. I would like the full string to appear when the user mouses over any cell in this column.

So far I have it working where a tooltip pops up for any cell in this column but they don't display the text. The tooltip always just says "Icon Tip".

**How do I get the qtip to display the variable val instead of the string "Icon Tip"?**

```
Ext.define('AM.view.user.List' , {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    .......
    initComponent: function() {
        function renderTip(val, meta, rec, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {
            meta.tdAttr = 'data-qtip="Icon Tip"';
            return val;
        };
        this.columns = [
            {header: 'First Name', dataIndex: 'FirstName', width: 75},
            {header: 'Last Name', dataIndex: 'Last', width: 75},
            {header: 'Perm', dataIndex: 'Perm', width: 75},
            {header: 'Comment', dataIndex: 'Comments', width: 150, renderer: renderTip}
        ];
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Figured it out on the sencha forums, the correct code would be:

```
function renderTip(value, metaData, record, rowIdx, colIdx, store) {
    metaData.tdAttr = 'data-qtip="' + value + '"';
    return value;
};
```

I guess there was some string/variable concatenation I needed to use

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?179016-Grid-cell-tooltip

Answer (score 1):

You already have the value, it gets passed as the first argument to the renderer. If you need more information, you also have the record.

Comment: Thank you for answering. What is the difference between the value and the record? I thought replacing 

   meta.tdAttr = 'data-qtip="Icon Tip"';

with 

    meta.tdAttr = 'data-qtip=val';

would display the cell value in the tooltip but it just say "val" for all cells now

Comment: Value is the value bound in the dataIndex, record is the whole model with all the values. Not sure how familiar you are with programming, but val is a variable. So there's a difference between = val and = "val";

Comment: Yeah I figured meta.tdAttr = 'data-qtip="Icon Tip"'; would show the string "Icon Tip" in the tooltip, which it did. I thought meta.tdAttr = 'data-qtip=val'; would show the string contained in the variable val in the tooltip but it only shows "val". Thanks for the reply!

Comment: figured it out from this thread http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?179016-Grid-cell-tooltip